# Chromium Browser History deletion

Tags: pi-3, chromium

How can I delete Chromium browser history at boot up on Raspberry Pi-3?

Answer (score 1):

These two commands clear chromiums cache:

```
rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/
rm ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

to execute this commands on boot edit your crontab file (more about [cronjobs](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)):

```
crontab -e
```

append this line to the end of the file:

```
@reboot rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/ && rm ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

**@reboot** executes the following commands to remove the chromium/chrome cache at each reboot of your pi but more on the reboot keyword [**here**](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)
Note: To use the @reboot function you have to be root

Hope I could help!